# moqui:In moqui how to access rest without sign any user

Tags: moqui

I've implemented an application using Moqui Framework. I provided url:http://localhost:8080/fvl-plus-runtime/rest/s1/example/examples 
It is getting error like:

User [null] is not authorized for View on AT_REST_PATH [/example/loginexamples/{username}]

Answer (score 1):

You can add ArtifactAuthz records for all users, like the ones already in place for admin users for the REST APIs. In general it is best to secure all API access, and that is how things are setup by default. There are various examples you can follow to see them in action, see the extensive comments in the rest.xml file (the XML Screen for the /rest path).

Comment: In the rest.xml for get json data is available.how to post data that can save in to database.for example we can take this http://localhost:8080/moqui-plus-runtime/rest/s1/moqui/users.  Can you send url that set data in to database for post

Comment: I have tried like this:http://localhost:8080/moqui-plus-runtime/rest/s1/moqui/users?emailAddress=la.ssashumar@gmail.com&newPassword=moqui&newPasswordVerify=moqui&firstName=makeit&phoneNumber=9877676544&username=xcvxcvxcv&lastName=skfdjfksf

Comment: And also i tried by placing All users,it gave me like this :HTTP Status 401 - User must be logged in for operaton list on entity users.          type:Status report
message :User must be logged in for operaton list on entity users
description;This request requires HTTP authentication.

Comment: See the examples in the rest.xml file. When sending data to the server you should pass a JSON body. With curl this is done using the -d argument. For authentication either use basic authentication (curl -u argument) or pass an api_key header (after getting an api_key, again see comments in the rest.xml file) like: -H "api_key: {apiKey}".

Comment: I have a problem with the session in REST service.I have created a url with the ExampleApp.xml that which user can login(URL:localhost:8080/moqui/ExampleApp/… second URL is this localhost:8080/moqui/rest/s1/example/examples at this point of time it is creating a new session ID(visit Table). This gives an error like User [null] is not authorized.Can you provide better way to achieve this.The above situation is happening when URL are hitting form MOBILE and we are using cordova version 6.1.1, ionic - HTML5 mobile ui framework version 1.7.14.

Answer (score 1):

This feature as been added in commit #44272ba. You are now able to create a new REST service and set require-authentication=anonymous-view or anonymous-all.

See [How to create a publicly accessible REST API in Moqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638825/how-to-create-a-publicly-accessible-rest-api-in-moqui) for more details.

Comment: I have a problem with the session in REST service.I have created a url with the  ExampleApp.xml that  which user can login(URL:http://localhost:8080/moqui/ExampleApp/UserLoginWebService?userId=john.doe&password=moqui).The second URL is this http://localhost:8080/moqui/rest/s1/example/examples at this point of time it is creating a new session ID(visit Table). This gives an error like User [null] is not authorized.Can you provide better way to achieve this.

Comment: The above situation is happening when URL are hitting form MOBILE and we are using cordova version 6.1.1, ionic - HTML5 mobile ui framework  version 1.7.14