# How to create a publicly accessible REST API in Moqui

Tags: moqui

What is the best way to create a publicly accessible REST API in Moqui? By public I mean an API that does not require prior authentication.

The only work around I found so far was to create a user "public_api" and grant him access to the desired services. The client applications then use this user to authenticate with the Moqui server.

Comment: What else have you tried? For example, have you tried an ArtifactAuthz record to grant access for the REST path in question to the ALL_USERS group? This is not a scenario I have tested, I just haven't run into a use case for it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an update in moqui-framework commit #44272ba to support the require-authentication element on the Service REST API resource, id, and method elements. Set this to anonymous-view or anonymous-all to allow access to REST API services without authentication or authorization. This follows the same pattern as is used for XML Screens to be accessible without login (like the POP Commerce ecommerce app).

Comment: I have tested this out and it is working perfectly. Thanks.