# I need to build separate java project and integrating with the moqui as intermediate

Tags: java, moqui

I need to build separate java project and integrating with the moqui as intermediate

I need to discover how to call moqui services from outer project

Comment: So ... what have you tried? Are you using any build tools or other tools for dependency management?

Comment: im still trying on it, i have project build on eclipse

Answer (score 1):

For calling services on moqui you can use remote procedures. your best bet is to call them through http with a rest api.

At "/apps/tools/dashboard" you can see the swagger apoi docs of different methods under the "REST API: Swagger UI" section

An example can be found when trying the moqui tools rest api at that section.
GET - "/rest/s1/moqui/basic/enums" will return a json with a list of the enums.

If you want to use a custom service, You need to declare an attribute in your custom services to allow remote access and can send http requests to it.

Some extra information can be found at:
https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/framework/System+Interfaces/Web+Service

If you run into authorization problems with the rest api, that's solved in this question:
[moqui:In moqui how to access rest without sign any user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562327/moquiin-moqui-how-to-access-rest-without-sign-any-user)